# powershell - class / function declaration issues

Tags: powershell

I'm new to `powershell` so I am not sure why I am getting the following error:

> missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition

But everything looks consistent from my java knowledge.

I have a `class { method1{} method2{} }` type of structure happening as follows:

**case use**

```
class DoSomething1
{

    <#
         .SYNOPSIS whatever
         .PARAMETER somevalue1
         .PARAMETER somevalue2
         ... etc
    #>

    function DoSomething1
    {
        [cmdletbinding()]
        param
        (
            [parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "help yourself")]
             $somevalue3
        )
     # will add code to constructor later
    }
}
```

I'm unsure what the problem is with it, because when I write my method as:

**alternative**

```
class DoSomething1
{
   DoSomething1()
   {
      # whatever
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if there's an advantage of one versus the other, or if I'm m using the keyword function out of context, but I wanted to apply the concept of `cmdletbindings` and get-help information further on by using `<# .SYNOPSIS details #>` in front of the function command.

Does anyone know what i am doing incorrectly?

Comment: You can't define PowerShell functions inside classes like that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just wanted to have member functions in a class, so how come it works when I write it the second type of manner, without using the "function" declaration keyword?

Comment: Because the second one is indeed the correct syntax for defining a class method! But unlike in Java or C#, OOP is not the prevalent paradigm in PowerShell. The ability to define classes is an afterthought, and arguably the _least_ mature part of the language. Forget about what you'd do in Java :)

Comment: fair enough, so at this point how would i be able to use the structure that works and make it behave like a cmdlet, such that when i run **DoSomething1()** without mandatory parameters, it tells you to input the parameter like in the first example.  I would additionally like to be able to run **get-help DoSomething** and have it spit out the information for the relevant method.  I will modify my initial question to include the example in the first case, because I don't know how to go about it in the second.  thank you for your kindness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, PowerShell is not quite like Java or C#, and classes are sort of "second-class citizens" with respect to PowerShell language features.

Instead, in PowerShell we can implement cmdlet-like behavior with something called [advanced functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) - like the one you already have:

```
function DoSomething1
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "help yourself")]
         $somevalue3
    )

    # do something with $somevalue3
}
```

PowerShell scripts are evaluated line by line, so if you put one of these function definitions in a script, any subsequent call to `DoSomething1` will invoke that function.

Depending in the size and scope of what you're trying to automate, you might find yourself with a large number of small self-contained functions like this. To better organize your code in larger projects, you can split function definitions into individual files, and then use the `.` invocation operator to execute them, which will make the function(s) "persist" in the current scope:

`Get-Something.ps1`:

```bsh
function Get-Something
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(<# ... #>)
  # ...
}
```

`Export-Somewhere.ps1`:

```bsh
function Export-Somewhere 
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(<# ... #>)
  # ...
}
```

`script.ps1`:

```bsh
# Import functions from other the script files
. .\Get-Something.ps1
. .\Export-Somewhere.ps1

# Now we can use the functions in here
Get-Something |Export-Somewhere
```

For more broadly reusable tools, you might want to consider organizing your functions into [modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules)